# How to store a Collection of Dates in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

If I have the following field in a JPA2 `@Entity`:

```
List<Date> associatedDates;
```

How do I get JPA2 to persist this field?

`@OneToMany` doesn't seem to work.

Is JPA2's `@ElementCollection` the best way to go? If yes, do I need to use a wrapper with the `@Entity` annotation instead?

The `serviceHistory` collection in [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/looking-forward-to-jpa-20-part) example uses this approach, but the `ServiceVisit` class encapsulates more information - I really only need to store a collection of points in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hibernate reference guide has all you need to know about [mapping a collection of elements](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-ofvalues), which this is, since Date isn't a mapped entity.